What we call the set of all nodes having a directed path to a node?
Let $i$ be a node in a graph. What we call the set
$$\mathcal{S}_i = \{j\colon \mathrm{node}~j~\mathrm{has~a~directed~path~to~node}~i\}?$$
Thanks so much!

I believe that I've heard "inset" and "outset" used for this and its opposite. I don't like it, because both those words have other meanings, and maybe these terms referred to the edges rather than the nodes at the remote ends.

I don't know a standard math term, but if people are familiar with the term "watershed" that would be a great analogy.

@JonathanZ Thanks so much for your kind reply. In some articles on control theory, e.g., "Distributed estimation based on multi-hop subspace decomposition", such a set with a limited path length $\rho$ is called "$\rho$-hop reachable set". Maybe we can call it a "reachable set" (but it seems to have another meaning in graph theory: the set of nodes $j$ having a directed path from node $i$).

@JohnHughes Thanks very much for your answer. Is "reaching set" a good name for it?

Would "predecessors" work?

@MJD Thanks very much! We can call it the set of predecessors of node $i$.

Principal-ideals (or lower-sets) for the pre-order of the transitive-reflexive closure of your digraph.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(order_theory)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_set
Since for every digraph $D=(V,E)$ we can form a pre-order $P=(V,\cup_{n=0}^{\infty}E^n)$ then $\mathcal{S}_i=[i]_{P}$ with us using relational composition to write $\small E^n=\underbrace{E\circ \cdots \circ E}_{n\text{ times}}$ for $\small n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\small E^0=\{(v,v):v\in V\}$.

Thanks very much for your insightful answer!

@Ryan No problem.

Node $i$ is said to be reachable from node $j$ provided that there is a directed path from $i$ to $j$.
Your set could be called the set of nodes that $i$ is reachable from.

Yes, it is a "reachable set" of node $i$ when we reverse the direction of all edges.

Is "reaching set" a good name for it?
